# Trying to find the maximum value of EACH group in my dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I've got a csv with 10+ columns and it's grouped based on an index number. For example,

```
index othercolumn othercolumn2 sample hits othercolumn3
1     cccc        bbbb         dog    4    aaaa   
1     cccc        bbbb         cat    1    aaaa   
1     cccc        bbbb         cat    2    aaaa   

2     cccc        bbbb         rat    1    aaaa   
2     cccc        bbbb         dog    1    aaaa   

3     cccc        bbbb         bird   1    aaaa   
3     cccc        bbbb         rat    42   aaaa   
3     cccc        bbbb         cat    3    aaaa
```

Is it possible to find the maximum number of hits for each "group" (by index)? I'm not too sure what to do in a situation where there is no highest hit, like sample 2, but that's not too important for now. For example, the desired output would be something like,

```
For index 1, the highest hits are 4 for sample dog.
For index 2, the highest hits are 1 for sample rat.       
For index 3, the highest hits are 42 for sample rat.
```

So far, I've used defaultdict to create a dictionary of lists for each group, or index. But I can't seem to get the highest number of hits and cleanly print that out. So far, this is what I have.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

groups = defaultdict(list)

with open('data.csv') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header row

    for row in reader:
        groups[row[1]].append([row[17], row[18]]) #row 1 is index, row 17 is my sample column, 18 is the hits column
        
print(groups)
```

Would appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas 'group_by' method along with the max function to calculate the required output.

Hope the following code will help you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
c =np.array(data.groupby("index").max())
for i in range(len(c)):
    print('For index '+str(i+1)+', the highest hits are '+str(c[i][3])+' for sample '+c[i][2]+'.')
```

output:

```
For index 1, the highest hits are 4 for sample dog.
For index 2, the highest hits are 1 for sample rat.
For index 3, the highest hits are 42 for sample rat.
```

Comment: This is really clean and simple, but I'm getting an assertion error for some reason with no further explanation. Would you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you, not that beautiful bot works!

```
import pandas as pd
# assign data of lists.
data = {'idx': ['1', '1', '1', '2',"2","2","2","3","3","3","8","8"],'sample': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat',"cat","dog","fish","dog","fish","ostrich","dog","cat"], 'hits': [1, 2, 3, 1,1,2,2,2,3,42,0,55]}
# Create DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["key"] = df["idx"].astype(str)+df["hits"].astype(str)
# Print the output.
df.head(10)

idx     sample  hits    key
0   1   dog     1   11
1   1   cat     2   12
2   1   dog     3   13
3   2   cat     1   21
4   2   cat     1   21
5   2   dog     2   22
6   2   fish    2   22
7   3   dog     2   32
8   3   fish    3   33
9   3   ostrich     42  342


max_idx = df.groupby(["idx"]).max("hits")
max_idx = pd.DataFrame(max_idx)
max_idx
    hits
idx     
1   3
2   2
3   42
8   55

max_idx.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
max_idx["key"] = max_idx["idx"].astype(str)+max_idx["hits"].astype(str)
df_max = df.loc[(df["hits"].isin(max_idx["hits"])) & (df["idx"].isin(max_idx["idx"]))& (df["key"].isin(max_idx["key"]))]
df_max
    idx     sample  hits    key
2   1   dog     3   13
5   2   dog     2   22
6   2   fish    2   22
9   3   ostrich     42  342
11  8   cat     55  855

for i, j, k in zip(df_max["idx"],df_max["hits"],df_max["sample"]):
    print("For index ", i," the highest hits are ", j," for sample", k,"")
For index  1  the highest hits are  3  for sample dog 
For index  2  the highest hits are  2  for sample dog 
For index  2  the highest hits are  2  for sample fish 
For index  3  the highest hits are  42  for sample ostrich 
For index  8  the highest hits are  55  for sample cat
```